# Sidekiq on production server gives error on runing

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-4.2

We are using Amazon AWS Ubuntu machine for our server.
Rails 4.2.7 and Ruby 2.3

I have installed redis with these instructions ([Redis](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart))

and installed sidekiq with [Sidekiq](https://thomasroest.com/2017/03/04/properly-setting-up-redis-and-sidekiq-in-production-ubuntu-16-04.html)

I started redis, then starting sidekiq with just `bundle exec sidekiq` it give me error as running the jobs

```
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ubuntu"
```

Not sure why this error. Any suggestions ?

Comment: It looks like the message from Postgresql. Are you sure your DB config is correct?

Comment: yes, because the app is running on the server with proper data.

Comment: However, @MarekLipka is right: you have an issue with DB connection. I guess, you have to provide _environment_ when start Sidekiq. Otherwise, your Sidekiq uses _development_ settings instead of _production_ one.

Comment: Just found out, we are using RDS. But i guess somehow redis is unable to connect to rds db ?

Comment: You got Postgresql error, not Redis one. Try to specify _environment_ like `bundle exec sidekiq -e production`.

Comment: Its working now. I changed the permissions for redis(it was on root level). & started with the production environment for sidekiq.

Answer (score 0):

Closing this thread as it has been fixed.

Changed the permissions for Redis from root level to user level.
And running sidekiq in production mode.